# Can I use the same password for TrueCrypt as what I used when creating my Public Key?

Tags: gpg, truecrypt, cryptography, keys

I created and published a Public Key using gpg.

I am now creating a TrueCrypt volume and wish to use the same password.  Does knowing my public key, in this instance, make my TrueCrypt volume become any less secure?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not expert, but I don't think there is any risk involved. Your gpg password is used to unlock your private key only. Your public should not contain any elements that can lead to your password.

Answer (score 3):

Ditto what Jeroen said. There's no technical issue here. The public key is a public document and there's no way anyone can derive from it the passphrase for your private key.

I will insert the usual warning here about using the same passphrase for more than one system, however. I wouldn't say it was a huge consideration here, since you're likely to keep both of the above passphrases very strong and safe; but if you're also using the same one for gmail/twitter/gawker/facebook etc., then your encryption is as weak as the weakest point in all of their collective password security systems.